# How to parse Joda time of this format

Tags: java, jackson, jodatime

I converted DateString of format `YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS` in my JSON and persisted to POJO using the code

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
this.startDate = format.parseDateTime(startDate);
```

When I convert the POJO back to JSON, the date is written like `2013-07-12T18:31:01.000Z`.
How do we parse the time string `2013-07-12T18:31:01.000Z` back to JodaDateTime object. What should be the formatter.
I used `YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS` and it didn't work

Comment: Why don't you use `Date` instead of a the formatted date? This will get rid of all your problems about formatting. You should only format the date as String to show to the user. Software should not care about date format when processing dates.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`2013-07-12T18:31:01.000Z` it is standart ISO date time format.
You can use standart Joda date time formatter [ISODateTimeFormat::dateTime()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime%28%29)
**Example:**

```
  String startDate = "2013-07-12T18:31:01.000Z";
  DateTime dt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(startDate);
```

in this case date will be converted to date in your time zone.
If you want ignore your time zone use `UTC` zone in formatter:

```
  String startDate = "2013-07-12T18:31:01.000Z";
  DateTime dt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).parseDateTime(startDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should append `X` to your pattern. The [`SimpleDateFormat` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) contains a full list of fields you can use in a `DateFormat`, including `X` for "ISO 8601 time zone".

An ISO 8601 time zone is specified as

> The number of pattern letters designates the format for both formatting and parsing as follows:
>
> > ```
> >  ISO8601TimeZone:
> >          OneLetterISO8601TimeZone
> >          TwoLetterISO8601TimeZone
> >          ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone
> >  OneLetterISO8601TimeZone:
> >          Sign TwoDigitHours
> >          Z
> >  TwoLetterISO8601TimeZone:
> >          Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes
> >          Z
> >  ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone:
> >          Sign TwoDigitHours : Minutes
> >          Z
> > ```

Answer (score 2):

The API doc is not entirely clear: one should read

OneLetterISO8601TimeZone means 'X' and yields Sign TwoDigitHours or Z,

hence something like -05

TwoLetterISO8601TimeZone means 'XX' and yields Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes or Z,

hence something like -0500

and ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone means 'XXX' and yields Sign TwoDigitHours : Minutes

hence something like -05:00